# SmartGWT DateTimeItem,how to show the hour and min PickerItem?

Tags: smartgwt

[image]

The SmartGWT DateTimeItem doesnot show the hour and min picker item ,how to show the hour and min picker item like the picture?
(the picture is use the RelativeDateItem)

Comment: please attach your code so far.

Answer (score 1):

I Have already found the answer,just set 
DateTimeItem.setType("datetime"),
then the DateTimeItem.setShowPickerTimeItem(true) will work.